# Should I check if file exists before responding via .sendFile()?

Tags: ajax, node.js, http, express

Say I have this route handler in my Express.js app:

```
app.get('/files/:name', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('path/to/files/' + req.params.name + '.html');
});
```

This path is used via Ajax on my site. I wonder if I should guard against situations where a file with the requested name does not exist on the server, in which case the server returns a 404 response. I can work with this, i.e. detect the 404 in the browser and act accordingly (e.g. display a message to the visitor). However, I'm not sure if this is a good approach. Is it OK to use the 404 response here, or am I supposed to try to avoid 404 responses if possible. (E.g. I could if a file with the requested name exists on the server and only use `.sendFile()` if it does.)

I'm worried that performing a manual check would only slow things down as `.sendFile()` already has this check built-in (i.e. it's possible to avoid this check and instead detect 404 responses in the browser which is what I'm doing right now and it works fine).

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with returning a 404 instead, as that's the 404's purpose.I'm not sure there really is any other common/practical alternative.

Good luck.